# URL en ajax jquery 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

Tengo la siguiente función en javascript:

```js
function fn_infobasica_tipo_doc(){
  var data = {
  action : 'lista_tipo_documento'
 }
 $.ajax({
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  url: "app/controllers/FormularioController.php",  
 })
  .done(function(data){
  $('#in_infobasica_tipo_doc').html('<option>Seleccione</option>' + data); 
   })
   .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0){alert('Not connect: Verify Network.'); } 
  else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {alert('Requested page not found [404]');} 
  else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {alert('Internal Server Error [500].');} 
  else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');} 
  else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {alert('Time out error.');} 
  else if (textStatus === 'abort') {alert('Ajax request aborted.');} 
  else {alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);}   
   });
}
```

En donde tengo como rutas a los archivos:

- app->controller->FormularioController.php
- app->js->Formulario.js

FormularioController es el archivo que necesito llamar, Formulario.js es el archivo en donde ejecuto la función de javascript, la cual me da como respuesta:

1. Utilizando la url: "app/controllers/FormularioController.php",  Internal Server Error (500)
2. Utilizando la url: "/app/controllers/FormularioController.php", Requested page not found [404]

Vale aclarar que con versiones antiguas de jquery me funcionan bien las rutas.

Sera que alguien identifica que esta mal con las URL?

Quedo atento.

Comment: puedes probar con `../controller/FormularioController.php` ?? Tiene pinta que te está cogiendo rutas genéricas.

Comment: Hola Alejandro. gracias por responder. Al hacer esto me arroja Requested page not found [404]

Comment: El error 500 es un error en el servidor. Sí llegó a ejecutar el `FormularioController.php` pero éste tiene una excepción no controlada. Deberías debugar el código de ese controller y ver por qué falla.

Comment: Gracias por la colaboración, efectivamente había un error de sintaxis en el controller cuando llamaba una clase. Ya me funciona correctamente.

Comment: @juan diego si puedes pon tú mismo la solución!!

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Practicamente todo esta bien configurado y corriendo de forma correcta, lo único es que estaba haciendo un mal llamado al archivo externo. Adicional en el php.ini en el manejo de error_reporting quedo configurado como E_ERROR. Saludos.